# How to manually start $(Rev:r) counter from specific number?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Say, I have a library which is already version 1.0.15

I migrate my build process to Azure DevOps, and want auto increment of build number. So in the build pipeline options, I set Build number format to `1.0.$(Rev:r)`.

But now it starts making builds at 1.0.1

So how do I artificially increment this to 15?

Answer (score 27):

Add a variable in your build definition like this:
[image]
And then set the Build Number Format like following:
[image]

You will get the counter to start from 15.

Comment: Thanks, do you have link to documentation for that counter function?

Comment: @Inrego It is still in-preview, but you could get some information here: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/pull/1489/files#diff-364a30a6897fc5fa754cb0755dcaf891

Comment: It's added to the official docs now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#counter

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such option to manually increment the `$(Rev::r)`

See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40898003/7073340)

As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/options?view=vsts&tabs=designer#build-number-format),

> Use $(Rev:.rr) to ensure that every completed build has a unique name.
>   When a build is completed, if nothing else in the build number has
>   changed, the Rev integer value is incremented by one.
>
> If you want to show prefix zeros in the number, you can add additional
>   'r' characters. For example, specify $(rev:.rr) if you want the Rev
>   number to begin with 01, 02, and so on.